# "0 answers" shouldn't be red for closed questions

Tags: feature-request, design

While browsing the [list of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm?tab=questions&sort=newest) I noticed that "Named groups from regular expression in case statement [duplicate]" had "0 answers" coloured red, even though [you lucky bastard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-42-2/), your question has already been answered.

"0 answers" should only be coloured red if the question isn't closed. In western cultures, red typically means that there's something wrong or important, but there's nothing wrong or important in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for closed questions, it's meaningful to clearly see whether or not there are answers. In particular, it's usually a very good idea to consider a closed question's answers in deciding whether or not to vote to reopen it, and also in deciding whether or not to vote to delete it.

So there should be a color difference. (And not having answers is just as *important* for closed questions as for open ones.) Now, it can either work the same as for open questions, or differently.

If the color scheme is different, it will be very confusing, and will lead to many incorrect assumptions about whether or not questions have answers. Working the same will produce the [least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), so the current behavior should be kept.

In addition, consider: Doesn't it make sense--based on the meanings of *red* that you've articulated--for closed questions that are more likely to merit deletion (because they have no answers, and thus no valuable answers) to show the number in red?

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to take into account whether a question has an answer or not when deciding whether to reopen it. But it's worthwhile taking it into account when deciding whether to delete a non-duplicate question.

Comment: So a "NARQ" with no answers should have "0 answers" coloured red, while a "Duplicate" with no answers shouldn't have "0 answers" coloured red. Hmm. That might be slightly confusing...

Comment: @AndrewGrimm No, *all* questions with 0 answers should have it colored red.

Comment: I was describing the conclusions from my train of thought, and showing that the conclusions from what I suggested wouldn't work very well. (Reductio ad absurdum)